# How to run pytest on a module rather than file or directory?

Tags: python, pytest

I have installed a third-party Python package (let's say it's named `pkg`) which contains pytest tests in a module `pkg.test`.

Typically, one invokes pytest from the command line or IDE on a directory or file. However, how can I *programmatically* run these tests from my own Python code?

I would like to do something like the following, where I use a *hypothetical* `pytest.run_tests_in_module` function:

```python
import pytest

pytest.run_tests_in_module('pkg.tests')  # runs tests inside pkg.tests
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a section in pytest documentation that directly answers your question: ["Calling pytest from Python code"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code).

The function is `pytest.main()`, and you can pass the same arguments you would pass via the command line.

To pass a python package as an argument instead of a directory, you may use `--pyargs`. It will force pytest to perform regular import to locate the package. So the full invocation for your example above will look like this:

```
pytest.main(['--pyargs',  'pkg.tests'])
```

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed close, but because `main` takes a *directory* as an argument (like the command line), it is not clear to me how to invoke it on the tests of a specific package, since I don't think there is a programmatic way of determining a package's tests directory. Do you see a solution for that?

Comment: I see pytest has a command line option for running the tests from a specific package: `pytest --pyargs pkg.testing`. Could you please add that bit to your answer so I can accept it as the full answer? Thanks!